# Get all input values to javascript with the same id

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to get all different values using javascript with the same id.

[image: Here is my input.]

Here is my input code:

```
<input type="text" id="full" name="full" value="2018-12-06">
<input type="text" id="full" name="full" value="2018-12-14">
<input type="text" id="full" name="full" value="2018-12-18">
```

When I alert the id of the inputs it show's the 2018-12-06 only. I want to disable the jquery datepicker but the 2018-12-06  is the only one read.

Here is my calendar.

[image]

and my javascript code:

```
var x = (document.getElementById('full').value);

var array = ["2018-12-25", "2019-01-01", x]
```

I want to disable all value with same id like the mention above,

Comment: You can't. IDs need to be unique. Add a class to each and use `getElementsByClassName` instead.

Comment: id is meant to be unique. use class if you want multiple.

Comment: omg! this my original code `echo "<input type='text' id='full' name='full' value=" . $row['date'] . " >";`

Comment: Not really a solution if there are other inputs without those IDs.

Comment: @Andy- of-course. The OP will need to massage this into a solution that works for them (otherwise I would have put this into an answer). If the OP wants to identify some constraints then we can be more precise.

Comment: getElementById will return you only one element as ids are meant to be unique. If you use getElementsByClassName, it'll return you an array of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID is used as an individual identifier. So it is illegal to use same Id for multiple elements. To get values of multiple elements use class instead of id.
You can use `getElementsByClassName()` function to read values of all elements with same class name

Alternative to `getElementsByClassName()` using jQuery

```js
var l = $('.full').length;
//Initialize default array
var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { 
  //Push each element to the array
  result.push($('.full').eq(i).val());
}
//print the array or use it for your further logic
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="full" value="2018-12-06">
<input type="text" class="full" value="2018-12-14">
<input type="text" class="full" value="2018-12-18">
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is `undefined` in IE 3. Do not use.

Comment: @gilbert-v Are you serious?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I was asking gilbert if they were serious because nobody in their right mind should care what IE 3 supports

Comment: yup i appreciate your answer.. i just trying to get all the values and put to array like this ["2018-12-06", "2018-12-14", "2018-12-18"]

Comment: @Marie, I request you to delete unnecessary comments, because it misleads other users of stackoverflow. Keep useful comments

Comment: thanks code works well! sorry for late reply just got home from school

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar A user recommended that somebody should avoid a feature because it is not supported by a browser for an operating system that hasn't been used in 20 years. I was pointing out that the idea is asinine. Maybe you should look up the definition of "misleading?"

Answer (score 3):

IDs must be *unique*. You should add a class to each element and then use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Because the method returns a nodelist to get each input value you need to iterate over it. For both these examples I've used [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but you might find a `for/loop` or `forEach` easier to use.

```js
const full = document.getElementsByClassName('full');
const arr = [...full].map(input => input.value);

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="full" value="2018-12-06">
<input type="text" class="full" value="2018-12-14">
<input type="text" class="full" value="2018-12-18">
```

An alternative might be to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelectorAll). This uses CSS selectors so you can pinpoint elements by their attributes instead:

```js
const full = document.querySelectorAll('[name="full"]');
const arr = [...full].map(input => input.value);

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="full" value="2018-12-06">
<input type="text" name="full" value="2018-12-14">
<input type="text" name="full" value="2018-12-18">
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('full'); doesn't work for me

Comment: If you dont want other people to edit your answer you should take the time to proofread it better before you post it. Of course that would cut into your "first answer" rep

Comment: You could just make a comment rather than fix something I'm already fixing.

Comment: @KielDred className is not the same thing as name. In your snippet `full` is the name, not the class.

Comment: @Andy I am not the one editing your answer. and you could just proofread your answer before posting it. You rush an answer out, you deal with community moderation moderating the community.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I know how this community works. It's the first time someone has been actively crippling my answer while I'm working on final edits.

Comment: Why didnt you make those final edits before you posted it? Because you were trying to rush the answer out so you would be the first to get votes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185159/discussion-between-marie-and-andy).

Comment: @mplungjan No need to apologise. I reacted to your edits by ignoring them :) I have never been in a position where someone decided to dive into and edit an answer I've _just posted_ without a courtesy heads-up in a comment first. It just rubbed me the wrong way.

Comment: I wrote comments and deleted them immediately because you should still be able to see them but no need to keep them under the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an element with the same Id, If you want to get all different values from another element using javascript you can use ClassName

```
<input type="text" class="full" name="full" value="2018-12-06">
<input type="text" class="full" name="full" value="2018-12-14">
<input type="text" class="full" name="full" value="2018-12-18">

var x = document.getElementsByClassName('full');
```

Comment: there is no method `.getElementByClassName()`

Comment: `Class="full"` also has a typo.

Comment: getElement**s**ByClassName - but querySelectorAll is a better choice